# How to update links to agents in the same patch as me

Tags: netlogo

I have a model in which each agent has an undirected link to all the other agents.  What I want to do is increment a count, stored with each link, when two agents share the same patch.  In other words to keep a record of social interactions.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

```
links-own [counter]
```

Then here's the shortest solution I can think of:

```
ask links [
  if [patch-here] of end1 = [patch-here] of end2 [
    set counter counter + 1
  ]
]
```

An alternative approach would be:

```
ask turtles [
  ask turtles-here with [self > myself] [
    ask link-with myself [
      set counter counter + 1
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: thanks for your short answer , but for second one does the '[self > myself]' means other than me?  can we use 'other turtles-here' ?

Comment: If a link connects two turtles, we don't want both turtles to increment the counter on the link; one is enough. Checking `self > myself` ensures that. (`self < myself` would work equally well.) The comparison is by who number.